# Remove background colors within cells

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting

I've gotten in the habit of changing the background color of modified chunks of code  using the `Format - Background Color` menu on the selected code. E.g.

[image]

Now I'd like to clear these out of a large notebook to start anew, but selecting all cells and setting the background color back to `None` using the same menu item doesn't work.  Is there another way to remove all these chunks of colored code from a notebook?

Running `Cell - Show Expression` reveals the internal structure is:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"test", "=", 
   StyleBox[
    RowBox[{"1", "+", "2", "+", "3"}],
    Background->RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]]}], ";"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.88184852903022*^9, 3.881848539448594*^9}},
 CellLabel->"In[19]:="]
```

but I don't know how to modify the internal structure of all cells programmatically.

Comment: I would suggest something like `NotebookGet[...] /. (Background -> ...) :> Sequence[] // NoteboomPut`. This should be a lot more robust & performant than doing the modifications via the front-end, and it has the benefit that you get a copy of the original notebook, rather than having to risk destroying something

Comment: There is a Remove Formatting somewhere in Edit menu, can't check atm. So select all and click it.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, somehow I overlooked `Format - Clear Formatting` which works!

Comment: @Kuba I realize now that `Format - Clear Formatting` is too broad for my purposes, because it removes all formatting (including the `TI` style that I use in usage messages). So I will have to stick with something like @LukasLang suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @LukasLang's comment, the follow seems to work for me:

```
old = Get["old.nb"];
NotebookPut[old /. StyleBox[stuff___, Background -> RGBColor[_, _, _]] :> stuff];
```

then save the new notebook.